# How to make that WPF Virtual keyboard hides my controls

Tags: wpf, focus, tablet, virtual-keyboard

I'm developing a WPF application for tablet.
Since the framework 4.6.2, the virtual keyboard appears when a control gains focus.

I have a TextBox :

[image]

When this one gains focus so it becomes hidden :

[image]

Exists it native solution for correct this ?
Or must I manage a scroll viewer ?
Or show a dialog with my TextBox ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an application of my own, I ended using [WPFTabTip](https://github.com/maximcus/WPFTabTip) which is open source and works like a charm. It is available through nugget also.

By using it you will need only one line of code:

```
TabTipAutomation.BindTo<TextBox>();
```

It automatically handles the visibility issue by moving the focused UIElement into view.

If you do not want to use the project you can see the source code and take what you need also.